# Check library version from third party code

Tags: c++, opencv

I have code that was implements the OpenCV library, however, I do not know what version of the library it was written with. Is there anyway to find out from the code what version of the library that it was intended to be used with?

The only references to the library in the code is:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
```

Comment: cv::getBuildInformation();

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know for sure given that limited information, unless *perhaps* if you can run `ldd` and `strings` on a built executable you have.  But I suggest that OpenCV 2.4.11 is very likely to work with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV was designed to be backwards compatible within every major version, that is the latest 2.X.Y revision should support any code written in version 2.X.Z. Since version 3.0.0 was released, any 2.X code may need to be reworked. [This](http://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-find-opencv-version-python-cpp/) guy explains how to check version using code.